# Mongodb Aggregate - Get sent and received message

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I'm building a simple chat functionality for my app. I'm having a little problem getting sent and received messages.

This my Message Schema:

```
const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    from: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    to: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User',
        required: true
    },
    text: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    seen: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false
    },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        required: true
    }
});
```

Supposed I have this Message documents:

```
[
  {
    from: "5fef2536ad845e385c34a22f",  // My Own ID
    to: "5fef2575ad845e385c34a232"   // Example user "John",
    text: "I sent this"
    ...
  }, 
  {
    from: "5fffdc903eaf522cb8d20994",  // Example user "Dave"
    to: "5fef2536ad845e385c34a22f"   // My Own ID,
    text: "Dave sent this"
    ...
  }
]
```

This is my take to getting sent and received messages

```
await Message.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $or: [ { from: req.user._id },{ to: req.user._id }]
    }
  },
  { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: '$to',
      from: { $first: '$from' },
      text: { $first: '$text' } 
     ...
    }
  },
  {
    $project: { 
      _id: 0,
      to: '$_id',
      from: 1,
      text: 1
    } 
  }
])
```

The above aggregation yields to:

```
[ 
  // This is the message I sent
  {
    from: "5fef2536ad845e385c34a22f",
    to: "5fef2575ad845e385c34a232",
    text: "I sent this"
    ...
  }
  
  ...
  // I CAN'T FETCH RECEIVED MESSAGES
]
```

I am able to get the last **Message that I sent** since I only grouped them with `to` which messages I only sent. I can't think of a way how I can simultaneously fetch both sent and received messages by grouping them separately.

Should I change the way I model my Message? I would be grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you are looking is `$facet` which helps to categorize your incoming data. You can run multiple aggregation parallelly as below. The below code may be an example to show you how to use `$facet`

Here I created two arrays which are `sent` and `received`. You can run separate individual aggregation stages to get your desired data

```
{
    $facet: {
      sent: [
        { $match: { from: "5fef2536ad845e385c34a22f" }},
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ],
      received: [
        { $match: { to: "5fef2536ad845e385c34a22f" }},
        { $sort: { createdAt: -1 } },
        { $limit: 1 }
      ]
    }
}
```

**Working [mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/D7W_Cuq-XxN)**

Comment: Hi @varman! Why do I get 2 documents for each ```sent``` and  ```received``` while I expected them to only have 1 each?

Comment: How do you separately identify what you sent and what you received?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't quite get what you mean.

Comment: Sorry that was my mistake, I updated "How do you separately identify what you sent and what you received?"

Comment: In my aggregation, I want to get the last messages that I sent or I received from user so in my ```$match``` stage of aggregation, I used ```$or``` whether I'm the sender or the receiver of the document.

Comment: Correct, what you can do is, you can use match stage inside the facet , then sort, then limit by 1. You will get the desired output.

Comment: You expect something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/D7W_Cuq-XxN

Comment: Thanks for the help!! Just one more question, how do I merge the ```sent``` and ```received``` into single array. Maybe there's an operator inside aggragation for merging arrays?

Comment: you can use `$concatArray`. Try yourself and let me know if you fail

Comment: Awesome! I used it like this and works perfect. ```$project: { result: { $concatArrays:  ['$sent', '$received']  }  }```